# Добавление столбца в несколько таблиц

Tags: oracle, база-данных, sql

Есть 20 таблиц, из них имена 10 начинаются на `test_*`. Как добавить в каждую из таблиц начинающиеся на `test_*` столбец `total`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE
  T_NAME VARCHAR2(50);
  CURSOR C1 IS
    SELECT TABLE_NAME TABS FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'TEST_%';
BEGIN
  OPEN C1;
  LOOP
    FETCH C1 INTO T_NAME;
    EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ' || T_NAME || ' ADD TOTAL NUMBER(10,3)';
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE C1;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Как это будет в контексте oracle Я не знаю, но могу подсказать очередность шагов:

1. Получаем SQL запросом список таблиц с префиксом test_. В mysql это выглядит так: SHOW TABLES LIKE 'test_%';
2. В цикле проходимся по каждой из них и при помощи ALTER TABLE добавляете нужный Вам столбец